# Instead of isinstance, use of try and except in Python 3.7

Tags: python, try-catch, except

I wrote a code to catch my error message using try and except (I want to write it without using isinstance) and I am getting the error message when the input is not an integer. The problem is, the program is giving me error message even if the input is valid integer. Please give me some suggestions to make it run. My code is given below:

I tried using exception clause but that did not work.

```
class Hotel:
    def __init__(self,room,catagory):
        if room != int:
            raise TypeError ()
        self.room = room
        self.catagory = catagory
        self.catagories = {"A":"Elite","B":"Economy","C":"Regular"}
        self.rooms = ["0","1","2","3","4","5"]

    def getRoom(self):
        return self.room

    def getCatagory(self):
        return self.catagory
        return self.catagories.get(self.catagory)
    def __str__(self):
        return "%s and %s"%(self.rooms[self.room],self.catagories.get(self.catagory))
try:
    room1 = Hotel(a,"A")
    room2 = Hotel(1,"A")
    print(room1.getRoom())
except:
    print("there's an error")
```

I am expecting:

there's an error

1 and Elite

A

Comment: Because, `if room != int:` is always `True`. This is not how you check type in Python.

Comment: `isinstance(room, int)` _really is_ the better pattern (if you're to use type checking at all), but `type(room) == int` is probably what you're looking for.

Comment: If you catch all errors like this you will also catch all possibilities to debug your code.

Answer (score 1):

You are checking if `room != int` . It will give you error always.

You have to check   `type(room)!= int` .
I have corrected the code below

```
class Hotel:
    def __init__(self,room,catagory):
        if type(room) != int:
            raise TypeError ()
        self.room = room
        self.catagory = catagory
        self.catagories = {"A":"Elite","B":"Economy","C":"Regular"}
        self.rooms = ["0","1","2","3","4","5"]
```